# object declare in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

```
a.hbrBackground=GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

error: cannot convert from 'void *' to 'struct HBRUSH__ *'
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Cannot execute the above code in vc++

Please check the code.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal for GetStockObject. You just need to cast it

```
a.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

Comment: Yup, unfortunate side-effect of a C API. GetStockObject can return different types of objects.